# Need to add a sum to a specific MDX string

Tags: expression, mdx

```
{strtomember("[Period].&[" + cstr(YEAR(dateadd("m",-11,now())))+"M"+
 right("0" + cstr(datepart("m",dateadd("m",-11,now()))),2) +"]")
:strtomember("[Period].&[" + cstr(YEAR(dateadd("m",0,now())))+"M"+
 right("0" + cstr(datepart("m",dateadd("m",0,now()))),2) +"]")}
```

The above sting shows me 12 month of periods. Problem is that I do not have a total for the periods.

Can anyone help me

Comment: You have to give more information. What do you mean by `total for the periods`?

Comment: Hi Sourav. The MDX is using the dimension [Period] which is a dimension showing months - and in the shown MDX I get 12 months showing when using it. The total of the months showing does, however, not have a total.

Comment: How does the output look now and how do you want it to be?

Comment: Do you have a mail where I can send a excel file showing preferred setup.

Comment: I would much prefer if you can give some screenshots here. I don't want to know the details, just some overview kind of stuff.

Comment: ok, but I cannot paste screenshot here, does not work.

Comment: Look like this.                  jan feb mar .... Sales                                                                                                           Should look like              jan feb mar .. Sum

Comment: To add screenshot/picture: Hit the edit button. Press 'Ctrl+G'. Add pictures.

Comment: Thanks, just tried but cannot add picture unless I have 10 reps, and I do not.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure,but from what I got, you need a static label **SUM** added to your output under which is displayed the aggregated measure values for all the months in the set built

If so, what you can do is to create a calculated member in the `Period` dimension as that can get you the desired label.

I am assuming you are using this set you built in some MDX query along with some measure to obtain the count. Below is on the lines of what can be done.

```
WITH MEMBER [Period].[Month].[SUM] AS 
SUM

(

    {
        strtomember("[Period].&[" 
        + cstr(YEAR(dateadd("m",-11,now())))
        +"M"
        +right("0"
        + cstr(datepart("m",dateadd("m",-11,now()))),2) 
        +"]")
        :
        strtomember("[Period].&[" 
        + cstr(YEAR(dateadd("m",0,now())))
        +"M"
        +right("0" 
        + cstr(datepart("m",dateadd("m",0,now()))),2) 
        +"]")
     }

     , 

     [Measures].[SomeCount]

 )


 SELECT UNION(
    {
        strtomember("[Period].&[" 
        + cstr(YEAR(dateadd("m",-11,now())))
        +"M"
        +right("0"
        + cstr(datepart("m",dateadd("m",-11,now()))),2) 
        +"]")
        :
        strtomember("[Period].&[" 
        + cstr(YEAR(dateadd("m",0,now())))
        +"M"
        +right("0" 
        + cstr(datepart("m",dateadd("m",0,now()))),2) 
        +"]")
     }  
    ,
    [Period].[Month].[SUM])  ON 0,

[Measures].[SomeCount] ON 1

FROM [YourCube]
```

As I don't know the exact cube structure, go ahead and modify the query as per the same.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your input. I use the MDX in a program called Prophix. When inputting the above it tells me that the expresssion "with" is incorrect.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the "actual" MDX you are using please?

Comment: Hi, I use it as above. If you could send you an image through email I can show you a simple example.

Comment: Please don't take it otherwise. I would love to help you. But exchanging data on email is going against the community guidelines. There are loads of websites where you can upload images. Try for instance [imgur](http://imgur.com/). Upload the image and share the URL.

Comment: That is what I want to add a total to far to the right.

Comment: How does you `Period` dimension look like? Can you give an example of a month please?